# Set default close operation on PApplet (Processing)

Tags: java, processing

There´s any methods to set the default close operation on PApplet?

I tried to embed the PApplet in a JFrame, but it wont init correctly, i need to set the window to dont close at exit, in JFrame i can just set it to DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE, dont know how to do in a PApplet. I'm implementing a confirm exit dialog, and i just want to close only when i confirm.

PApplet already have a frame, but it's not a JFrame, so i can´t just call setDefaultCloseOpreation.

I´ve added an window listener to get the window closing action:

```
//frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "Want to save all unsaved data?",
                    "Exit confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

            switch(confirm) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                System.out.println("Data saved, closing...");
                break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                System.out.println("Data lost, closing...");
                break;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                System.out.println("Close canceled.");
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

In the cancel option i want to close this dialog and keep open the application, this way without "do nothing on close" every option i choose close the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem embedding the PApplet on JFrame, but as the example show in the processing documentation is very simple, it don´t work as expected.

Here´s the code working:

```
public class Application extends PApplet {

public void setup() {
    size(600, 480, JAVA2D);
}

public void draw() {
    background(255);
}

public void closeApplication() {
    exit();
}

public static void main(String _args[]) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Embbed Applet");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    final Application applet = new Application();
    applet.init();

    panel.add(applet);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(600, 510);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                "Want to save all unsaved data?",
                "Exit confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            switch(confirm) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                // Save data
                applet.closeApplication();
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                applet.closeApplication();
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                // Do nothing
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation of PApplet at http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html shows how a PApplet may be embedded into a Frame, and explicitly states that "...*there's nothing to prevent you from embedding a PApplet into a JFrame*". When you use a pattern according to the `ExampleFrame` shown there (but extending JFrame), you should be able to set the desired default close operation and attach your listener.

Answer (score 1):

A while back I ran into this same problem. I'm not *sure* that this code solved it, but I think it helped? There are some window listeners already there, this code removes them. I also dimly recall having to run it after a few frames because they hadn't been initialized or something immediately after the program starts or something. You can give it a shot, anyway:

```
  WindowListener[] wls = frame.getWindowListeners();
  println("Removing " + wls.length + " window listeners.");
  for (int i = 0; i < wls.length; i++) {
    frame.removeWindowListener(wls[i]);
  }
  frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
      checkExit();
    }
  }
  );
```